# sed to print a line with at least 3 digits duplicating digits after 4th digit

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I'm trying to write a script in `sed` that gets a filename as an argument.

My goal is to print all lines in the file that contain at least 3
digits. After the 4th digit, all digits should be repeated. I need a solution using `sed`.

**Example input file:**

```
abc 1 def2 3 ab45 z11
123 zy
ab1cd2ef3gh4z56
abc12aa
```

**Desired output:**

```
abc 1 def2 3 ab455 z1111
123 zy
ab1cd2ef3gh4z5566
```

---

What I have tried:

```
sed '/[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9]/d' ./F1
```

I don't have any idea how I can duplicate all numbers only after the 4th digit.

Comment: This is homework, right? Ask your teacher for clarification as the question is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU sed, you can do the following:

```
$ sed -E '/([[:digit:]].*){3}/!d;s/[[:digit:]]/&&/5g' infile
abc 1 def2 3 ab455 z1111
123 zy
ab1cd2ef3gh4z5566
```

The first command, `/([[:digit:]].*){3}/!d`, deletes all lines that don't contain at least three digits.

The second command, `s/[[:digit:]]/&&/5g`, repeats digits; the `5g` flag translates to "every occurrence from the fifth one onwards". The behaviour when mixing a number flag with `g` is not specified by POSIX; GNU sed behave in the desired way.

The `-E` flag is just for convenience; without it, we have to escape `()` and `{}`:

```
sed '/\([[:digit:]].*\)\{3\}/!d;s/[[:digit:]]/&&/5g' infile
```

If your sed does not understand `-E`, you might use `-r` instead. `-E` has been accepted by GNU sed for years (but was undocumented), and BSD seds use `-E` as well. POSIX will include `-E` for sed, as documented [here](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528); some older systems will only understand `-r`, though.

Comment: @Micael Sorry, I meant to "improve", not "reject" your edit as you raise a good point, but I mis-clicked...

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is absolutely the wrong tool for this, but it's a fun challenge:

```
sed -E -e '/([^0-9]*[0-9]){3}/{ h; s///; 
    s/([0-9])/\1\1/g; x; s/(([^0-9]*[0-9]){3}).*/\1/; G; s/\n//; }' input
```

Basically, you hold the line, then strip out the leading portion (the first 3 digits).  Then you duplicate all the digits, swap that into to hold space bringing the original line back to the pattern space.  Delete the tail, then append the new tail from the hold space back to the pattern space.

Comment: May I ask how does `s///;` work please? Maybe some point to documentation?

Comment: An empty pattern repeats the last match. Doesn't this duplicate digits from the 4th on, though, instead of the 5th?

Comment: @PesaThe See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses, "The empty regular expression..."

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks, I didn't know that. I should definitely brush up on my `sed` skills. And yeah, it repeats even the 4th digit.